# How do I add to existing PDF template with Wicked_PDF?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I have an existing PDF template that I'd like to fill out within a Rails application and save to a new PDF. Is there a way to do this using Wicked PDF or is there another tool or gem better suited to the task?

Comment: Wicked PDF is used for converting HTML to PDF. Not for filling out existing PDF forms or templates.

Answer (score 1):

Wicked PDF is used for converting HTML to PDF. Not for filling out existing PDF forms or templates.

A quick google search returned [HexaPDF](https://github.com/gettalong/hexapdf) or [Origami](https://github.com/gdelugre/origami) as potential options for editing PDF files with Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

wicked pdf is not for filling existing pre created pdf. you may need to look at prawn, prawn-form for that. Its DSL based pdf library for ruby and ruby on rails.

A quick search got me into this issue.
please take a look, [wicked pdf issues github](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/691)